# Installing MS Office on Server

Tags: asp.net, windows-server, excel-automation

I need to install MS Office on a windows server, in order to use excel automation in my asp.net web app. I am aware that microsoft strongly advices against this, but for the thing I am using excel automation, their warnings shouldn't apply. Now I have seen numerous posts on how to get excel automation to work on a server, however I can't seem to find anything about how to install Office on a server. When I try to install it I get an error:
`The procedure entry point K32GetProcessImageFIleNameW could not be located in the dynamic link library KERNEL32.dll`
Which I have discovered, through google, means that I am trying to install office on an unsupported OS. There must be a way around this, since there seem to be so many people using excel automation on their servers. Can anyone help me out with installing office on my server or finding a workaround to installing it, so that I can still use excel automation?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into this: https://code.google.com/p/excellibrary/

Excel automation on your server will be process intensive and is not the best approach. I know that this library is a couple of years old, but it should suffice if you're ok with outputting to `.xls` Excel spreadsheets.